# Partially transparent text box

Tags: beamer, boxes, transparency, posters

I am trying to make a poster using `beamer`. Can any one please reply me, my question is:

How can I make my boxes **partially transparent** so that my background will be visible through the boxes?

Answer (score 10):

The following was taken verbatim from the [PGF documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (section **20 Transparency**, p 234):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill,draw}]
  \draw[line width=2mm,blue!50,line cap=round] (0,0) grid (3,2);
  \node[opacity=0.5] at (1.5,2) {Upper node};
  \node[draw opacity=0.8,fill opacity=0.2,text opacity=1]
    at (1.5,0) {Lower node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It translates directly to [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

Comment: It might as well happen that the OP wants to make the `block` environment transparent.

Comment: Thank  you so much. Could you please, tell me - How Can I use this , for background image (.pdf) , also for several boxes that may contain image and text together.  Or How Can I use a block that is quite transparent so that my background image will be partially visible but the text are very clear like your example.

Comment: @Mahzabin: You cannot set the transparency of an external image that you include. Do you want to include a background image, and then overlay it with some transparent text?